# Integrate Java project with Ant in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a question regarding using Java Ant projects in Eclipse. Initially I was creating an Ant java project from the command line just to see how it works. Now I want to use it in Eclipse and I am not sure how to proceed.

So the initial file structure is as follows:

```
project2/
    src/java/com/pe60t0/project2/component1/HelloPe60t0.java
    lib/
    ...
```

I have the following build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="HelloPe60t0" basedir="." default="main">
    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
    <property name="main-class"  value="com.pe60t0.project2.component1.HelloPe60t0"/>
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="application" location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
    </target>
    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path refid="application"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>
    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>
    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
</project>
```

And the HelloPe60t0.java is defined as follows:

```
package com.pe60t0.project2.component1;

public class HelloPe60t0{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello pe60t0 wuzup?");
    }
}
```

When I am to type "Ant" in the command line it compiles and runs properly. When I am in Eclipse and click on the build.xml -> Run As Ant Build everything runs properly again. However, Eclipse does not accept that the HelloPe60t0.java is in com.pe60t0.project2.component1 folder and complains about directory structure. So I am not sure why in the command line everything compiles and runs properly and eclipse complains.

Any help will be appreciated. Please note I am new to Ant and I have always had problems working with directories and folders, so please excuse me if I have missed something obvious.

Regards,

Petar

Comment: Could you add the following information to your question: How have you added your Java projects to eclipse? What are the build path properties (found in `Properties > Java Build Path`) of your project? Is your directory `project2/src/java` contained in your Java Build Path? What is the exact error or problem displayed in your problems view?

Answer (score 2):

Both your ant build and your eclipse project should set `src/java` as the source directory, rather than `src`. The source dir is supposed to contain the root of the package tree.

Answer (score 0):

From your ant file it looks like your source is in project/src, and you compile it into project/classes.  If you create a java project in eclipse, it will using project/src and compile into project/bin.  You can check the settings by right-clicking on your project and going to `Properties>Java Build Path`.  The first thing to check is if they match.